# Pagination Rule in ADF Rest API COPY activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to download JSON data from REST API Source and insert it into csv file. I am able to do this through looping.

Now I am trying to do this with REST Copy activity inbuilt pagination support but I came across some issues for which I need some clarification whether it's possible to do or not.

Below are the API details

```
Base Url - https://abc.xyz.com/eu/analytics/zz/v15/analytics-metrics/xyz-reports/{id}/

Relative Url - data?size=100
```

First call the API url look like this

```
https://abc.xyz.com/eu/analytics/zz/v15/analytics-metrics/xyz-reports/{id}/data?size=100
```

The {id} get its value from a previous web activity which generates the id.

During second call the url look like this

```
https://abc.xyz.com/eu/analytics/zz/v15/analytics-metrics/xyz-reports/{id}/data?size=100&nextDocumentId=eyJzZWFyY2hBZnNzgsMTA2NTcxMTZdfQ%3D%3D
```

so in the first call the url doesn't have nextDocumentId and in the subsequent call it appends the nextDocumentId.

The WEB activity which sends the first call it brings the below response

```
{
  "Response": "[{}]",
  "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "CF-Cache-Status": "DYNAMIC",
    "Next-Document-Id": "eyJzZWFyY2hBZnNzgsMTA2NTcxMTZdfQ==",
    "Link": "<https://abc.xyz.com/eu/analytics/zz/v15/analytics-metrics/xyz-reports/{id}/data?size=100&nextDocumentId=eyJzZWFyY2hBZnNzgsMTA2NTcxMTZdfQ%3D%3D>; rel=\"next\"", 
    "Page-Size": "100",
    "Total-Elements": "196",
    "Total-Pages": "2"  
  } 
}
```

When I am trying to apply the AbsoluteUrl pagination properties the next link contain some unwanted characters like <, >; rel="next".

I am able to clean it up using below expression and added into AbsoluteUrl under body dynamic content as shown below

```
@substring(activity('Download Report data').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['Link'],add(indexOf(activity('Download Report data').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['Link'],'<'),1),add(indexOf(activity('Download Report data').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['Link'],'>'),-1))
```

[image]

It throwing **RestInvalidPaginationRule** error.

Second option I tried using QueryParameter Pagination rule but I am not sure how to pass it as mentioned above the nextDocumentId is not require in the 1st call but needed in subsequent call.

Please let me know whether the pagination support works for this scenario or not.

Thanks

Comment: So, everytime you need the above expression output of the previous page response for the current page URL?

Comment: yes the substring expression remove those unwanted characters and give the next page link. But I think as per my understanding the dynamic expression doesn't support , but not sure as the UI provides the space for adding dynamic expression.

Comment: Yes, as every time you need the dynamic expression, Pagination in ADF doesn't support for this scenario. The loop approach is the workaround for it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Not sure what's the use of dynamic expression builder in pagination ,it created confusion for me that I might be doing some thing wrong with the expression.

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure what's the use of dynamic expression builder in pagination

The dynamic content in this is used to specify only the property value in the current response body. **In the case, when the property value is changing for every iteration** in copy activity, dynamic expression will be used specify it.

**Sample:**

[image]

You can give any dynamic expression but the value of it should be the property name from the current response.

[image]

If it's not in the property value, it will throw the `RESTInvalidPagination error` like below.

[image]

And coming to your case, **AFAIK**, this is the reason why the dynamic expression doesn't support your scenario. The looping approah might be better option considering your requirement.

**Check the similar issues for reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/31904/how-to-use-dynamic-values-in-pagination-rule

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1477173/adf-copy-activity-pagination-how-to-pass-variable